# CSS flex not changing width from 1 to 2 or 3

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why does my flex box not change width when changed. I am following along this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJSoEo8JSnc and at minute 7:40 he changes the flex on class box-1 from flex:1 to flex:2 and then flex:3. When he does this it makes box-1 take up more of the width. When I do the same it does not change the width as it does in the video. I am trying to duplicate on this

```css
.container-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kkQFh8p.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
}

.container-1 div {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 3;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h3>Box One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <h3>Box Two</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <h3>Box Three</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

width different background than the video but all else is the same. https://codepen.io/centem/pen/pozRMXm

Comment: you only use box-1 classes, nothing wrong. If you use the right class with the right values, it becomes coherent : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PoYpqJx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different class names in your HTML. Replace `box-1` of the 2nd and 3rd child to `box-2` and `box-3` respectively. With your current code all the boxes will have the same `flex: 3` and will distribute equally between them instead of the `3 1 1` ratio that you desire.

```css
.container-1 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/kkQFh8p.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
}

.container-1 div {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.box-1 {
  flex: 3;
}

.box-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.box-3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h3>Box One</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <h3>Box Two</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <h3>Box Three</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```